# How to set up IMU_UM6 on UART?

Tags: ros, beaglebone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to connect an IMU_UM6 to a UART port on my BeagleBone. The default location in the imu_um6 node to set the sensor is ttyUSB. How do I set this up for streaming from the UART?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64300/how-to-set-up-imu_um6-on-uart?/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The UART usually enumerates under a device name like `/dev/ttyS0` or `/dev/ttyS1`.

Try changing the `port` parameter to the hardware UART device name in your launch file.

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="imu_um6" type="imu_um6_node.py" name="imu_um6_node" output="screen" respawn="true">
        <param name="port" type="string" value="/dev/ttyS0"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-06-04**:
Thanks for the info. With  dmesg | grep tty  the uart ports "seem" to be at ttyO0 - ttyO5. I have the UM6 attached to uart5 on the Beaglebone but I'm still not getting the imu_um6 node to find the actual sensor.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2013-06-04**:
I'm not sure what you have/haven't done, but it does appear that the UART pins aren't enabled by default in the Angstrom image according to here: http://www.gigamegablog.com/2012/01/22/beaglebone-coding-101-using-the-serial-and-analog-pins/  Perhaps you have to enable the correct pins?

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-06-04**:
Yep, that was it. Once I set the pin mux it connected to the UM6 just fine.